# Gitlab http basics access denied

Tags: gitlab

I tried using this commands before getting errors

```
   git remote add name url
   git add .
   git commit -m 'message'
   git push -u name master
```

Answer (score 0):

The question should be more clear. Error messages should be posted.

If you logged in GitLab with GitHub account, you'll have to set up a password for GitLab in order to log into GitLab account.

The fastest way to do so is to change your password in GitLab. You should see only new password fields.

After that, you'll have no trouble pushing.